# How do I check if UIActivityTypeAirDrop exists

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller, airdrop, uiactivitytypeairdrop

I'm using the `UIActivityViewController` to show a share sheet within some iOS Apps. iOS 7 introduces a new type of `UIActivity`: `UIActivityTypeAirDrop`.

This is declared as an extern string in the `UIActivity.h` file... Essentially I'm trying to exclude the airdrop type from my share sheet which is all working fine, but this codeset needs to be backwards compatible with previous versions of iOS.

I know to check for a method I can use `respondsToSelector:` but is there any similar method I can use to check if the string is declared, or should I resort to switching on the system version? (Which is never a good way to go normally)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`UIActivityTypeAirDrop` is an NSString constant which is essentially gonna be a pointer so you can check if that pointer is NULL. If it's not, this activity type exists and you can exclude it. Else do nothing about it.

```
if (&UIActivityTypeAirDrop != NULL) {
    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop];
}
```